# How to skip tags with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

If I have the follow html structure, how do I print just the "print this" text?

```
<div class="a">
 <div>
  <strong>
   Skip this
  </strong>
  <span>
   skip this
  </span>
 </div>
 print this
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use *contents* for this;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<div class="a">
 <div>
  <strong>
   Skip this
  </strong>
  <span>
   skip this
  </span>
 </div>
 print this
</div>""")

# the text you need is the last element of the contents    
soup.find('div', {'class': 'a'}).contents[-1].strip()
# u'print this'
```

Comment: Hi, I have a follow up question.  Some data has <br/> after the text, is there a way to handle that?  For example. Thanks

    <div class="a">
     <div>
      <strong>
       Skip this
      </strong>
      <span>
       skip this
      </span>
     </div>
 print this
<br/>
</div>

Comment: Not exactly sure what your document looks like. You might try something like `next(x for x in reversed(soup.find('div', {'class': 'a'}).contents) if isinstance(x, NavigableString) and x.strip() != "")`. Check from the end of contents and filter out tags and empty string.